# TTL for mongoid in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

As stated at mongodb website, i can expire records with .ensureIndex({state:1},{expireAfterSeconds: 10}). But how this could be implemented from rails? Thanks

Comment: Please note: TTL is 2.2 only, of course we dunno what Mongo version you are using but still...Also most drivers have not been update to the 2.2 API, I am unsure how Rubys functions are implemented, also what do you mean by: `But how this could be implemented from rails? ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you are using MongoDB 2.2, the Ruby driver should already support this via the Collection's [create_index()](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#create_index-instance_method) and [ensure_index()](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#ensure_index-instance_method) methods. Index options are passed directly to the server. The underscored symbols in the API docs are translated internally as a convenience (e.g. `:drop_dups` sets the `:dropDups` option). You should be able to do:

```
@collection.create_index([['state', Mongo::ASCENDING]], :expireAfterSeconds => 10)
```

For mongoid specifically, it looks like you can pass custom options for indexes as well, per [this documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Indexes/ClassMethods#index-instance_method).

Comment: actually one can't just pass expireAfterSeconds in options, valid option types are: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/indexes/validators/options.rb#L10

Comment: I assume mongoid would want to stick to the underscored pseudonyms defined by the driver. Rather than wait for `expire_after_seconds` to appear, perhaps you can access the raw collection class from mongoid and run the command yourself?